# I would like to use YES/ NO value in Blazor CheckBox control instead of true / false with data bind option

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I would like to use YES/ NO value in Blazor CheckBox control instead of true / false with data bind option. Need two way binding, not using change event.

```
<InputCheckbox @bind-Value="@CheckBoxValue" />

@code {

    private string CheckBoxValue = "Yes";
}
```

Comment: Your `CheckBoxValue` is really a property. You can supply arbitrary `get` and `set` bodies to it. Create a backing variable, create 2 properties referencing it, where one gets and sets it from bool for blazor use, and the other gets and sets it from string for your app needs.

Comment: Why?  This is not a display value, why do you want to change the default property name?

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
<InputCheckbox @bind-Value="@CheckBoxBool" />

@code {

    private bool CheckBoxBool;
    private string CheckBoxValue => CheckBoxBool ? "Yes": "No";
}
```

You can also use an extension method for bools if you what to display them as Yes/No.

```
public static class BoolExtensions
{
    public static string AsYesNo(this bool value)
       => value ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```